# Tool to measure wifi performance

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm looking for a tool to help me analyse the throughput of my  wifi network (I'd like to experiment a bit with antenna positioning and placement).

I know that tools like inSSIDer exist and show the network strength, but these don't seem particularly precise. Ideally the tool would undergo and measure a throughput test (by transferring data over the connection) and report the results, rather than a tool that passively measures and reports.

Comment: I find a combination of inSSIDer and ookla's speedtest to be invaluable. They measure two entirely different, but related, elements.  There are "network analyzers" but the most solid solution for me so far is that combo.

Comment: You may also find Nirsoft's WiFi Info View, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html , helpful -- it shows signal quality, both immediate and average. It is a portable application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're doing a multi-way test and scrutinizing airtime usage, you don't need a Wi-Fi-specific tool for this.

I'd recommend you install IPerf 2.0.x (I don't trust 3.x yet) and use that.

Put one of your IPerf machines on a wired Ethernet LAN port of your router. Note that IPerf does an "upload" (client sends to server) test by default, so to test your wireless download (router to client) speed, you'll want to run the wired machine in client mode and the wireless machine in server mode.